# iOS version distribution of my own app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Apple publishes the [iOS version distribution across all devices](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/):

[image]

**Is there a way to see the iOS version distribution for a given app that I have published?**

Comment: Based on what point in time? Point of purchase, point of latest upgrade, point of most recent use?

Comment: Any would do, by most recent use is the best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [**iTunes Connect Analytics**](https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/), select your app and go to **Metrics → Active Devices** or **Sessions** and choose **View By → Platform Version**. This will give you a breakdown of the iOS version installed per the category you selected.

Keep in mind this data only began reporting in iOS 8 and is opt-in only. You can hover the "Opt In Only" text to view the percentage of your users who have opted in which should provide a little guidance in extrapolation.

Comment: Can I figure out the percentage of iOS 7 users from this feature? I am considering a feature that would not work in iOS 7, and would like to estimate the number of users I will be forcing out of the next update.

Comment: @AdamMatan There are a few easy-to-integrate analytics platforms that do exactly what you want and so much more.